# Sails js won't redirect after update

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, sails.js

I'm using sails.js with Passport for user creation and sessions. I've created a user profile update screen with a submit button.

```
<form action="/user/update/<%= req.user[0].id %>" method="post" class="js-user-edit-form">
  ...
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/users.edit.js"></script>
```

This is the js file:

```
$(function() {
  $('.js-user-edit-form').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: $('.js-user-edit-form').attr('action'),
  data: $('.js-user-edit-form').serialize()
})
.done(function(data) {
  window.location.href = "/user";
})
.error(function() {
  alert("Oops! Something went wrong.");
});
return false;
})
});
```

Relevant routes:

```
'get /user/edit':          'UserController.edit',
'get /user':               'UserController.index',
'get /user/:id':           'UserController.show',
```

User controller:

```
edit: function(req, res) {
User.findOne(req.user.id)
  .done(function(err, user) {
    return res.view({
      user: user
    });
  });
```

},

My problem is that is that after i submit the update i get redirect to:

```
http://localhost:1337/user/update/53d033e685b861924ab55870
```

Rather than being redirected to

```
http://localhost:1337/user
```

When i use the console it outputs this:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:1337/user/update/53d6207f40dee700004698e2".
```

As far as i can tell the javascript isn't working, because at the end of it i redirect to /user but that doesnt happen.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `return res.view({` with `return res.json({`?

Comment: no. what would that do? and I think that part of the reason its not working is becuase i have a toJson method in user model which intercept the chain of calls. I've eddited the question with the console message.

Comment: Seems to me that despite your `event.preventDefault();`, your HTML form is being POSTed to the value in the `action` attribute.  To test, you could change that attribute to "http://google.com", and temporarily hardcode the `/user/update/53d033e685b861924ab55870` in your `$.ajax()` call.